# How to remove duplicate lines from a file and writing them in file in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-handling

Below code gets all the Links in a HTML File and Writes it into a text file. But it is also copying the duplicate lines ( Links ). Is there any way to make sure it won't write the link which are already inside the file ? Any method So that I don't have to manually code a functionality ?

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):

    def handle_starttag(self,tag,attrs):
        if tag=="a":
            if attrs.__len__>0:
                for a in attrs:
                    if a[0]=="href":
                        print a[1]
                        f=open("index_link.txt","a+")
                        f.write(a[1]+"\n")

def main():

    parser=MyHTMLParser()
    f=open("index.html")
    if f.mode=="r":
        contents=f.read()
        parser.feed(contents)
    else:
        print ("No file found")
    f=open("textfile.html","w+")
    f.write(contents)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: cache the link written links in dict should work

Comment: Keep a set of links and check whether the link's already in it?

Comment: Set might work. Whats the syntax for checking duplication in set ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to record found links yourself, e.g. with a `set`:

```
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.links_found = set()

    def handle_starttag(self,tag,attrs):
        if tag=="a" and attrs:
            for a in attrs:
                if a[0]=="href" and a[1] not in self.links_found:
                    self.links_found.add(a[1])
                    print a[1]
                    with open("index_link.txt","a+") as f:
                        f.write(a[1]+"\n")
```

You can also use a simple list, if you want to keep the links, in order, instead of writing them directly to a file:

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.found_links = []

    def handle_starttag(self,tag,attrs):
        if tag=="a":
            attrs = dict(attrs)
            if "href" in attrs and attrs["href"] not in self.found_links:
                self.found_links.append(attrs["href"])

def main():
    parser = MyHTMLParser()
    with open("index.html") as f:
        contents = f.read()
    parser.feed(contents)
    with open("index_link.txt","w") as f:
        f.write('\n'.join(parser.found_links) + '\n')
    with open("textfile.html","w") as f:
        f.write(contents)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: 'super(self).__init__' showing error that it **must be type, not instance**

Comment: Should be `super(MyHTMLParser, self).__init__()`

Comment: Look at what you're doing. You put the link into a set and then immediately write it to the file. How did that help?

Comment: Plus this reopens the file every time a link is found. That is unnecessarily inefficient and complicated in addition to be chatty and hard to read.

Comment: @mirosval: so that's as near to the OP's code as possible, for solving the problem.

Comment: I understand, but should we not strive to help him anyway? His code has flaws, so we help him fix them or point them out at the very least.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple just make use of **list data type which will be list of links**, here I am using **html_links** variable

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):

    def __init__(self):
        super(self).__init__
        self.html_links = []
    def handle_starttag(self,tag,attrs):
        if tag=="a":
            if attrs.__len__>0:
                for a in attrs:
                    if a[0]=="href" and a[1] not in self.html_links:
                        print a[1]
                        self.html_links.append(a[1])
                        f=open("index_link.txt","a+")
                        f.write(a[1]+"\n")

def main():
    parser=MyHTMLParser()
    f=open("index.html")
    if f.mode=="r":
        contents=f.read()
        parser.feed(contents)
    else:
        print ("No file found")
    f=open("textfile.html","w+")
    f.write(contents)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Sets do this faster (O(1) lookup time), and do de-duplication for free, so you can just add _every_ link to the set and save yourself a step inside the conditional.

Answer (score -1):

Use [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set). Instead of writing your links directly into a file (which is inefficient anyway), try this:

```
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init(self)__:
        super(HTMLParser, self).__init__()
        self.my_links = set()

    def handle_starttag(self,tag,attrs):
        if tag != "a" or attrs.__len__ == 0:
            return None

        for a in attrs:
            if a[0] == "href":
                self.my_links.add(a[1])
```

Then retrieve links:

```
parser = MyParser() 
# ... do your parsing here
links = parser.my_links 
with open('path/to/file', 'w') as f:
    for link in list(links):
        f.write(link)
```

Comment: So the writing part will be done in main function ? rather then in method ?

Comment: at class level, there is no `self`. `my_links` shouldn't be a class attribute anyway.

Comment: Why does `handle_starttag` returns `None`?

Comment: A set is unordered. Not sure, the OP want's to keep the order.

Comment: `writelines` writes the links without new-lines.

Comment: 1. Fixed the `self` that should not have been there, but if you just leave it like this, you dont really need a complex constructor as there is no need for it. 2. OP's version implicitly returns none if the ifs dont pass, I have rewritten that to be a bit cleaner and easier to read. 3. Replaced writelines with `write()` in a loop

Comment: @mirosval: you should *not* use class attributes here. You have to define `my_links` in `__init__`. `write` does also not add new-lines.

Comment: @Daniel You are right! I looked into it and you're completely right. I fixed my code. Thanks :)